# starting from SSP spectra to evaluate galaxy spectrum and observed mag

Tags: galaxy, spectra, magnitude, flux, stellar-population

I know that the galaxy spectrum, namely the flux per unit wavelength versus the wavelength, is the sum of the Simple Stellar Population (SSP) spectra at a fixed redshift (e.g. similar to eq. 1 in [Bruzual&Charlot 2003](https://academic.oup.com/mnras/article/344/4/1000/968846), but at fixed time). Then, integrating the spectrum of the galaxy in a certain filter band, I obtain the (observed,with the k-correction) magnitude.

Now I am wondering if the following operations to evaluate the galaxy spectrum and then the observed galaxy magnitude are equivalent or not:

METHOD (1):
I have N SSP forming my galaxy at fixed redshift. I perform the first and second operations N time, for each SSP:

- convolving the SSP spectrum with a chosen filter and integrating it in the filter wavelength band (following e.g. [Blanton+03](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1086/342935/fulltext/), but beware that my fluxes are k-corrected, or redshifted) and obtain the observed AB magnitude `mag_i`
- from the observed AB magnitude, I compute the integrated flux in microJansky: `flux(uJy)_i = pow(10,(29-(mag_i+48.6)/2.5)`.

  Now I want the total integrated flux (integrated flux of the galaxy):
- I sum up the fluxes computed in the previous passage (coming from the observed AB mag of each SSP) `flux_tot = sum(flux_i)`
- From the total flux, I re-compute the observed mag  `mag_tot=2.5*(29-np.log10(flux_tot))-48.6`.

METHOD (2)\

- I firstly sum up the spectra of the SSP all together, obtaining the galaxy flux per unit wavelength versus the wavelength
- I convolve it with the filter, I integrate it in the wavelength band and obtain the observed AB mag `mag_gal`.

In principle, the `mag_tot` of the first method and the `mag_gal` of the second method should be the same, right?

Comment: Yes, and the second method is (obviously) much more computationally efficient. (I'll admit I don't really see why in Method 1 you keep converting mag_i to flux(uJy)_i -- you should be getting flux_i after the convolution; how else do you determine mag_i?)

Comment: yes, you're right. It's because SSP spectrum is normalized to 1 Msun, so I need to rescale it by the mass of the SSP (omitted in flux_i computation I show; I know I can directly rescale it in the integration, but I need this passages for my purpose). Now I wonder why the second method doesn't give me the same result of the first...